# How do I convert a git repository to mercurial?

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, tortoisehg

I've been developing a java application using git as source code repository. I'd like to share the project with other java developers and hg seems to be most used by them.

My question is how do I convert a git repository to hg?

If I tried googling "convert git to hg" and every search hit is about converting from hg to git. I'm also using [TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: If you need to convert from mercurial to git instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/883452/git-interoperability-with-a-mercurial-repository

Comment: That last paragraph does not make sense. A typo?

Comment: @Tshepang: I wanted "git -> hg" but got "hg -> git". I'll edit this question but I guess people got it anyway since there are answers now.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

The [`hg convert`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension) utility isn't on by default after installation. In order to set it as such add the following to your `.hgrc` file.

```
[extensions]
hgext.convert=
```

If you're using [TortoiseHg](https://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) on Windows then this file resides in your home directory as `mercurial.ini`. After this setting change you will be able to use the `hg convert` utility.

Comment: On Ubuntu the system wide change can be made at /etc/mercurial/hgrc

Comment: On Windows, using TortoiseHg, it can be enabled by using the Global Settings menu item from the TortoiseHg shell extension menu in the Extensions section under Global Settings.

Comment: The description is somewhat incomplete as it doesn't specify that hg will need access to git for the conversion or else you get the error "cannot find required "git" tool".

Answer (score 42):

By using the [Mercurial Convert extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension)

> Add the following lines to your `.hgrc` or to enable the extension :

```
[extensions]
hgext.convert=
```

And typing a

```
cd src
hg convert --datesort . dst
```

(even though it can [lead to some issues](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/pipermail/mercurial/2007-December/016061.html)...)

Note:: [metrix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/969879/metrix) reports that this might not work:

```
     hg convert --datesort src dst
```

> **Note:** there happens to be a bug with `hg convert` if you perform this command from a directory other than the source directory.
>   You will get the following error:

```
abort: cannot read tags from git-repo4/.git
```

> Confirmed with git 1.7.9 and Mercurial 2.6.2 on Windows XP

Comment: If that answer included the `.hgrc`setup instead of linking to it it would be comprehensive.

Answer (score 17):

You may want to look at the http://hg-git.github.com/ utility: a Git plugin for Mercurial

This plugin is originally developped by the guys of GitHub, and allows the convert from git<->mercurial losslessly. In theory, you could even be able to clone the hg repository.

Comment: This is a better solution than converting the repository. It would be a better answer too, if it had more detail. One line answers are next to useless.

Comment: @naught101, thanks for the suggestion, I've added some more info here to read directly.

Comment: after you install & set up hg-git use hg gexport & hg gimport to convert between them.

Answer (score 9):

[Distributed revision control with Mercurial](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/hgbookch1.html) states:

> The revision control tools supported
>   by convert are as follows:
>
> - Subversion
> - CVS
> - Git
> - Darcs

So maybe you don’t need any additional tool?

Comment: Unfortunately "hg convert" is not available in tortoisehg

Answer (score 6):

The convert extension may work for you, but if it doesn't, you might want to check out [tailor](http://progetti.arstecnica.it/tailor) which is a general purpose tool for converting among the various distributed SCMs.

Answer (score 2):

You could just not convert it at all.  Just use the [Hg-Git](http://hg-git.github.com/) plugin!  No one will know the difference.

Answer (score 2):

New player in town: [git-remote-hg](http://felipec.wordpress.com/2012/11/13/git-remote-hg-bzr/). It provides native bridging support in git.

Just:

```
hg init ../hgrepo
git push hg::$PWD/../hgrepo
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `Git` folder with all my Git repositories I created the `Git2Hg.cmd` file with the following content:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Git\bin
hg convert %1
```

Now I can convert a Git repository to Hg by typing this in a CMD:

```
Git2Hg "Folder Name"
```

Answer (score 0):

Hg-Git Plugin or  if u use for windows or migration from one to another visit here [2](http://www.appveyor.com/blog/2014/02/23/converting-mercurial-repository-to-git-on-windows)[Windows GIT]