# git for mercurial like git-svn

Tags: svn, git, mercurial

Hello is there a tool for git that allow to work with mercurial repositories

F.e. for svn there is a git-svn package, that allows to clone/commit/update from svn and work in a git way..

So is there some tool for mercurial for that ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git interoperability with a Mercurial Repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/883452/git-interoperability-with-a-mercurial-repository)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this related SO question:
[Git interoperability with a Mercurial Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883452/git-interoperability-with-a-mercurial-repository)

It seems that [`hg2git`](http://repo.or.cz/w/fast-export.git) is of interest.  It is part of the [`git fast-export`](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git-core/docs/git-fast-export.html) family of tools.

If you want `hg` to push/pull from a `git` repo, then consider the [Hg-Git Mercurial Plugin](http://hg-git.github.com/).

Comment: `hg-git` is *very* nice, but its designed to allow Mercurial to be a client for Git.  Doing it the other way around is possible, but it's slightly convoluted.  As a Mercurial user I find it *very* handy though.

Answer (score 0):

There is ['bridge support for Mercurial and Bazaar'](http://felipec.wordpress.com/2012/11/13/git-remote-hg-bzr-2) now distributed as part of git: git-remote-hg is in the git tree under `contrib/remote-helpers`.  It is not full-featured, so it will allow you to clone a hg repo in git, but more advanced operations like tagging and branching may not work.

I recommend [gitifyhg](https://github.com/buchuki/gitifyhg).  It's a fork of git-remote-hg, and the team responsible seems to be more responsive to bugs, so you can tag and branch just as you ordinarily would with a git repo, except it's Mercurial at the backend.  It's available in pypi, so you can just `easy_install gitifyhg`, and then:

```
git co gitifyhg::ssh://my.repo//path/to/repo
```