# Mirroring a HG project from Bitbucket to Github

Tags: git, mercurial, workflow, github, bitbucket

Is there an efficient workflow to mirror a project that is mainly hosted on bitbucket using Hg, to github?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/883452/git-interoperability-with-a-mercurial-repository

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You could use a tool like [**`hg-git`**](http://hg-git.github.com/) to:

> - setup a Git repository somewhere that you have push access to,
> - and then run `hg push [path]` from within your project. For example:

```
$ cd hg-git # (a Mercurial repository)
$ hg bookmark -r default master # make a bookmark of master for default, so a ref gets created
$ hg push git+ssh://git@github.com/schacon/hg-git.git
$ hg push
```

> This will convert all our Mercurial data into Git objects and push them up to the Git server.
>   You can also put that path in the `[paths]` section of `.hg/hgrc` and then push to it by name.

[image: hg-git]

Comment: Thanks. I did take a brief look at hg-git, but I see that it is still in an alpha state. I tried installing it in cygwin but I am having some stability issue with it at the moment.

Provided this works, though, it is definitely a useful tool in the workflow.

Answer (score 13):

If you use Mercurial for a project you can quickly and easily make a git mirror of your project so that git users can contribute.  I created a tutorial about using `hg-git` to manage Mercurial mirrors on GitHub.

It covers how to get started with a GitHub account, how to push up a project from Mercurial to GitHub, and how to accept contributions (pull requests) from GitHub.  Here's a link to the blog post: http://hgtip.com/tips/advanced/2009-11-09-create-a-git-mirror/ archived at http://web.archive.org/web/20100811223113/http://hgtip.com/tips/advanced/2009-11-09-create-a-git-mirror/

Comment: The website mentioned above seems no longer available.

Answer (score 12):

> 'git-remote-hg' is the semi-official Mercurial bridge from Git project, once installed, it allows you to clone, fetch and push to and from Mercurial repositories as if they were Git ones:

Add [git-remote-hg](https://github.com/felipec/git-remote-hg) to your bin path. Then you can mirror as [mentioned on github](https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository).

```
git clone --mirror  hg::https://bitbucket_repo
```

then, go into your cloned repo

```
git remote set-url --push origin https://github.com/exampleuser/mirrored
```

finally, sync your mirror

```
git fetch -p origin
git push --mirror
```

Comment: This is much better than accepted answer as the result will be a true mirror with all tags and branches.

Comment: check your OS repos, ie fedora package is available: `dnf install -y git-remote-hg`

Answer (score 6):

As of July 2013 there is [BitSyncHub](http://www.metallapan.se/bitsynchub/) a web service for automating this process via a BitBucket post-receive hook. You will need to grant the service write permission to your GitHub repository though (add *bitsynchub* as a contributor).

Answer (score 3):

I'm reporting from Feb 2019. I just encountered this problem, followed [@vonc's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2670347/10892982) to use [hg-git](http://hg-git.github.io), and filled a few missing steps to make it work. Here I'll provide a more detailed guide:

1. Install hg-git by cloning its [repository](https://bitbucket.org/durin42/hg-git) somewhere and making the 'extensions' section in your ~/.hgrc file look something like this:

```
[extensions]
hggit = [path-to]/hg-git/hggit
```

I found the most up-to-date installation instructions in the source repository: https://bitbucket.org/durin42/hg-git. So keep an eye that.

2. Install [dulwich](https://www.dulwich.io) if not already: `pip install dulwich`.
3. Create a new empty repository on GitHub, for example https://github.com/user/git-mirror.
4. Clone the hg source repository, and push it to the git mirror:

```
$ hg clone https://bitbucket.org/user/hg-source
$ cd hg-source
$ hg push git+ssh://git@github.com/user/git-mirror.git
```

Answer (score 1):

One more available solution to quickly convert: https://github.com/frej/fast-export

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Git-hg Mirror service](https://githgmirror.com/) to do this (including mirroring a GitHub repo to Bitbucket, or syncing bidirectionally).