# Using git-remote-hg on windows

Tags: python, git, mercurial, hg-git

According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13354944/867294 it should be fairly easy to set up git to work with mercurial "no dependencies or anything".

This doesn't seem to work all that smooth on Windows tough.

I tried to follow this guide

https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/Guide-to-git-remote-hg

After fixing the makeFile to work on my system and building git i couldn't call git-remote-hg because it complained it couldn't find the python interpreter, all tough it's configured correctly.
So i manually called it with

```
C:/Python27/python.exe git-remote-hg clone C:/TestMercurialRepo
```

This is now giving me the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "git-remote-hg", line 99, in <module>
    sys.exit(HgRemoteHelper().main(sys.argv))
  File "d:\development\msysgit\git\git_remote_helpers\helper.py", line 196, in m
ain
    repo = self.get_repo(alias, url)
  File "git-remote-hg", line 33, in get_repo
    if repo.capable('branchmap'):
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mercurial\repoview.py", line 205, in __get
attr__
    return getattr(self._unfilteredrepo, attr)
AttributeError: 'mqrepo' object has no attribute 'capable'
```

How can i fix this ?
If there is a pre build version anywhere then that would be super awesome because i feel like i'm doing way to much to get this to work.

Comment: Why do you want to interact via `git` with a remote mercurial repository, and on Windows? `hg` has much better support on Windows, and non-native interactions will have their quirks.

Comment: @vonbrand - While I question the wisdom of his choice too, the fact remains he wishes to do it that way and should be able to.

Comment: @Omnifarious, my point is that there are less painful ways of doing what (I presume) is wanted here. Check out [X Y problems](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341).

Comment: @vonbrand - That's applicable if the person has problem X, chosen solution Y and hasn't even considered solution Z. But I presume the solution of 'just use Mercurial' has indeed occurred to the OP.

Answer (score 8):

I got this to work today on Windows. Basically, since the msysgit distributions have no Python support, I took Felipe's git-remote-hg.py file and used py2exe to package it up as an executable. Afterwards, I put all of the py2exe output into the 'libexec' folder under my Git installation directory, and it works.

For it to work, you need:

1. Python 2.7
2. The Mercurial Python module (windows installers [here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/downloads))
3. py2exe (windows installers [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/py2exe/files/py2exe/0.6.9/))
4. Felipe's git-remote-hg python script (save raw to file [here](https://github.com/felipec/git/blob/fc/master/git-remote-hg.py))

Create a file named setup.py that contains:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['git-remote-hg.py'])
```

Save the file to your file system and run the following command:

```
python setup.py py2exe --include mercurial
```

py2exe will produce a folder called 'dist' that contains the output. Copy the contents of that folder into the libexec\git-core folder under your main Git installation folder (e.g., C:\Program Files(x86)\Git).

Now, you should be able to clone from a Mercurial repo using the Git client.

(Note: I wrote these steps in a bit of a hurry, so please post back if I've left out anything).

Comment: I think I followed all the steps correctly, but when I try and use the script I get `LoadLibrary(pythondll) failed`

Answer (score 0):

I will have to investigate a bit further, but this looks like `git-remote-hg` might depend on a particular version of Mercurial being installed. In particular one in which the `repo` object supports the `capable` method.

This looks like a bug in git-remote-hg code. Any version of Mercurial new enough to have `repoview` is also new enough that every kind of repo object should support the `capable` method. So I'm guessing the object that has the problem is one being created by git-remote-hg.

Anyway, it's quite apparent that git-remote-hg uses the Mercurial Python code to do it's work. So there is a dependency between them.

Also, your backtrace does not match the code at https://github.com/felipec/git/blob/fc/remote/hg/contrib/remote-helpers/git-remote-hg, and so it's difficult to debug your setup.

Comment: My file is a generated file that is generated during the build, that is based on this file:  https://github.com/msysgit/git/blob/694fb7247b0bb3a3f9810f1350f997ebdb6008ae/git-remote-hg.py    Except for the first two lines which are deleted in my git-remote-hg file 
I'm not sure what the relation is between these files